# Changing a string whilst running app

Tags: android, string

I have made an app which starts with a screen where the user enters a password. I have text at the bottom saying `"You have 3 attempts remaining"` and would like to make it so that it counts down from 3 to 2 to 1 every time the password is incorrect.(I already have an IF else statement where I call a new activity if the password is correct and can add this method to the else) but I'm not sure how to update a string?

I was thinking of using a For loop and have tried this:

```
public String textAttempts(View view){
    String attemptsRemaining = getString(R.string.attempts_Remaining);
    int loopVal; 

    for(loopVal=1;loopVal>=0;loopVal--){
       String attmeptsRemaining =   
                   attemptsRemaining.replace(loopVal, loopVal); 
    }
    return attemptsRemaining;
}
```

However it gets very confusing due to having to convert int to string and that also makes the replace statement unhappy.
Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Strings XML file:

```
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Stock Control System FINAL</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="enter_password">Enter Password</string>
<string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
<string name="button_confirm">Confirm</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
<string name="title_activity_main_menu_passed">MainMenuPassed</string>
<string name="button_stock">Stock</string>
<string name="button_products">Products</string>
<string name="button_supplies">Incoming Supplies</string>
<string name="button_suppliers">Suppliers</string>
<string name="button_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main_stock">MainStock</string>
<string name="title_activity_main_menu">MainMenu</string>
<plurals name="attempts_remaining">
    <item quantity="one">You have one attempt remaining.</item>
    <item quantity="other">You have %d attempts remaining.</item>
</plurals>

</resources>
```

Comment: You are also creating a new string, and never returning it. `attmeptsRemaining` is not the same as `attemptsRemaining`

Answer (score 1):

nr4bt's answer is a good one, but it doesn't change the sentence's from plural to singular when needed. What you'd want to do is this:

In your `strings.xml` add:

```
<plurals name="attempts_remaining">
        <item quantity="one">You have one attempt remaining.</item>
        <item quantity="other">You have %d attempts remaining.</item>
</plurals>
```

In your code do this:

```
attemptsRemainingTextView.setText(getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.attempts_remaining, attempRemaining, attempRemaining));
```

Read more about [Android plurals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorry its taken me a while to get back to you but I'm quite new to android development and I'm getting an error for plurals in setQuantityString(R.plurals... saying plurals cannot be resolved or is not a field. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you add the code to your strings.xml? Can you post it somewhere so I can see your strings.xml file? Make sure you import your project'a R and not Android's. But make sure you added the plural part correctly to your strings.xml

Comment: Cheers again for your help! i've added the strings XML file

Comment: From your comment I'm not sure if it's working now or not. If it is please accept my answer. If not can you elaborate on your problem? Maybe post the strings.xml file?

Comment: No i'm still getting the "plurals cannot be resolved or is not a field" error, I've added the strings XML file as an edit on the question

Answer (score 0):

declare a global variable like

```
int attempCount;
```

and every time you check the attempt, increase the count by 1, and in your textAttempts simply put this value.

```
// you can declare your R.string.attempts_remaining like "you have %s remaining attemp"
public String textAttempts(View view){
    String t= getString(R.string.attempts_Remaining);
    return String.format(t, "" + attempCount);
}
```